# How to retrieve a nested list object inside an object in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the data of a nested list object that I have inside one object in Firebase. I've tried to search some similar question and I can't find any similar question. I've spent a lot of time trying to get this object but I always get null values, but I can see in data snapshot that the whole object is there.

I can get the Car object, but I'm not able to get the list of users that I have inside this object.

This is my database look in Firebase:

```
Car
 -KloSsiZiz6DfvBhp9dk
   - timestamp: 1496602610880
   * users
       - QsqgxinR4TabETV5DaAAg4fW9fE2
       - k2L3B6rV0NTpLQsMfWhw2MrTZl42
             - displayName: "bob"
             - email: "t@t.com"
             - guestType: 2
             - uid: "k2L3B6rV0NTpLQsMfWhw2MrTZl42"
       - m5PfDgvbGrM9IXZKgdO04TTvYMO2
       - qXkogeDvLGPlP7LNFrWnAgbVzaQ2
       - r2T34mSC0DggDejFxcb91SjqFVq1
   - date: "2017-08-04T02:00:00Z"
```

My Model Car:

```
    private List <User> users;
    private Object timestamp;
    private String date;

    public Car(){}

//Getter and setter
```

My Model User;

```
 private String displayName;
    private String email;
    private String photoUrl;
    private int guestType;
    private String uid;


    public User() {}

//Getter and setter
```

This is the way that I have the Car object

```
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 Car car= (Car) dataSnapshot.getValue(Car.class);

//At this point, I can get the values inside the car object, but if I try to do car.getUsers() I get a null.
             }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try following code inside your Model car,

```
public Map<String, User> users;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Map` instead of a `List`. So in order to solve the problem you need to make the change in your model class. Than to retrive the users please use: `car.getUsers()`. This line of code returns a `Map`. Iterate over the map and get the users.

Hope it helps.